# Tensorflow 2.0 image data load

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import IPython.display as display
from PIL import Image 

AUTOTUNE=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

import pathlib
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin='https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',fname='flower_photos', untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

import pathlib
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin='https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',fname='flower_photos', untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

CLASS_NAMES = np.array([item.name for item in data_dir.glob('*') if item.name != "LICENSE.txt"])
CLASS_NAMES

BATCH_SIZE = 32
IMG_HEIGHT = 224
IMG_WIDTH = 224

list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(data_dir/'*/*'))

def get_label(file_path):
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, '/')
    return parts[-2] == CLASS_NAMES

def decode_img(img):
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3) #color images
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32) 
   #convert unit8 tensor to floats in the [0,1]range
  return tf.image.resize(img, [IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT]) 
#resize the image into 224*224 

def process_path(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label

labeled_ds = list_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

for image, label in labeled_ds.take(1):
  print("Image shape: ", image.numpy().shape)
  print("Label: ", label.numpy())
```

output for the last for loop:
Image shape:  (224, 224, 3)
Label:  [ True False False False False False]

Now that I have created this, how can I actually load this into my neural network, meaning, how can I initialise my test_img and test_labels ?
I'm very new to neural networks and just recently worked myself through all the maths, would be very helpful if someone understands my problem.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? This sounds like the kind of question that can be answered by guides and tutorials, or by looking at the documentation. Have you done any research?

Comment: How should I continue now that I have got this labeled_ds. How can I bring it into the form of testimgs and testlabels? I‘ve searched for some tutorials but could‘nt find one for this specific issue